# center submenu under variable width parent

Tags: css, center

sorry if this has been asked before, I've looked and have tried several options but I can't seem to get this to work. I want to center my submenu. Each parent item has variable widths, and the submenu items also have variable widths.. This is my code:

```
.menu-wrap ul li{margin:0;padding:0;display:inline-block}
.menu-wrap ul li>a{font-size:16px;color:rgba(0,0,0,.6);display:block}
.menu-wrap ul li>ul{position:absolute;float:left;left:0;right:auto;top:90px;width:auto;padding:10px 0;background:#fff;opacity:0;border-top:solid 1px rgba(245,130,32,1)}
.menu-wrap ul li.parent:hover>ul{opacity:1}


<ul class="nav menu">
  <li class="item-101"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
  <li class="item-129 parent"><a href="/about/about-us.html">About</a>
    <ul class="nav-child">
      <li class="item-148"><a href="/about/about-us.html">About Us</a></li>
      <li class="item-116"><a href="/about/testimonials.html">Testimonials</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="item-114 parent"><a href="/services/services-page-example.html">Services</a>
    <ul class="nav-child">
      <li class="item-122"><a href="/services/services-page-example.html">Services Page Example</a></li>
      <li class="item-123"><a href="/services/services-page-example-2.html">Services Page Example 2</a></li>
      <li class="item-124"><a href="/services/services-page-example-3.html">Services Page Example 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="item-154"><a href="/case-studies.html">Case Studies</a></li>
  <li class="item-115"><a href="/gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
  <li class="item-149"><a href="/frequently-asked-questions.html">FAQ's</a></li>
  <li class="item-117"><a href="/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Currently it's just left aligned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came across this guide recently and found it helpful.

http://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Comment: Thanks for that, definitely helped me out. I'll be bookmarking this :)

Comment: Linking to a website explaining properties is not an answer to a question. The user found it useful, but you didn't answer the question.