# Group of images wont center CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css, alignment, margin

im having trouble getting this selection of images to align to the center in CSS. Here is the html code im using:

```
<a class="socialIcons" href="LINK" title="Facebook" alt="FB"><img src="img/Social/Facebook.png" width="100px" height="100px"  /></a>

<a class="socialIcons" href="LINK" title="Soundcloud" alt="cloud"><img src="img/Social/SoundCloud.png" width="100px" height="100px" /></a>

<a class="socialIcons" href="LINK" title="Tumblr" alt="falling"><img src="img/Social/Tumblr.png" width="100px" height="100px" /></a>

<a class="socialIcons" href="LINK" title="Vimeo" alt="VMO"><img src="img/Social/Vimeo.png" width="100px" height="100px" /></a>

<a class="socialIcons" href="LINK" title="Youtube" alt="YT"><img src="img/Social/YouTube.png" width="100px" height="100px" /></a>
```

And here is the CSS for these images:

```
a.socialIcons {
margin-left: 10px;
}

a.socialIcons:hover {
opacity: .8;
filter:alpha(opacity=80);

}
```

Ive tried so many methods such as an absolute position, margins, etc but none of them work. The images just stick to the left.

I hope someone here can help me out, as its for an assessment due tomorrow.

Thanks all!

Comment: you're probably after `text-align:center;`

Comment: Add `text-align: center` to parent container.

Comment: I linked to a really great resource for css centering in a previous answer. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26091760/center-submenu-under-variable-width-parent/26091808#26091808.

Answer (score 0):

Give your parent container css "text-align:center"

```
 <div class="images">
    <a class="socialIcons" href="LINK" title="Facebook" alt="FB"><img src="img/Social/Facebook.png" width="100px" height="100px"  /></a>

    <a class="socialIcons" href="LINK" title="Soundcloud" alt="cloud"><img src="img/Social/SoundCloud.png" width="100px" height="100px" /></a>

    <a class="socialIcons" href="LINK" title="Tumblr" alt="falling"><img src="img/Social/Tumblr.png" width="100px" height="100px" /></a>

    <a class="socialIcons" href="LINK" title="Vimeo" alt="VMO"><img src="img/Social/Vimeo.png" width="100px" height="100px" /></a>

    <a class="socialIcons" href="LINK" title="Youtube" alt="YT"><img src="img/Social/YouTube.png" width="100px" height="100px" /></a>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
a.socialIcons {
margin-left: 10px;

}
.images{
    text-align:center;

}
a.socialIcons:hover {
opacity: .8;
filter:alpha(opacity=80);

}
```

[Here is jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/parthi04/r540qd9s/)

Answer (score 0):

You must add wrapper div in this structure and set `text-align:center` to that.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Rochefort/rv3658q3/)**

Answer (score 0):

You just need to wrap links in a container with "text-align: center;"

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <a class="socialIcons" href="LINK" title="Facebook" alt="FB"><img src="img/Social/Facebook.png" width="100px" height="100px"  /></a>
    <a class="socialIcons" href="LINK" title="Soundcloud" alt="cloud"><img src="img/Social/SoundCloud.png" width="100px" height="100px" /></a>
    <a class="socialIcons" href="LINK" title="Tumblr" alt="falling"><img src="img/Social/Tumblr.png" width="100px" height="100px" /></a>
    <a class="socialIcons" href="LINK" title="Vimeo" alt="VMO"><img src="img/Social/Vimeo.png" width="100px" height="100px" /></a>
    <a class="socialIcons" href="LINK" title="Youtube" alt="YT"><img src="img/Social/YouTube.png" width="100px" height="100px" /></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    text-align:center;
}
```